# Ограничения двумерного vector'а

Tags: c++, vector, динамические-массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли у двумерного vector'а ограничение по размеру. И, если да, то какое оно в обе стороны.

Comment: Ну, в стандартной библиотеке двумерного вектора нету вовсе, насколько мне известно.

Comment: `std::vector::max_size()`

Comment: Эта операция позволит узнать макс.размер массива в принципе?

Comment: Огромное спасибо!